# How to enable PostSharp for all methods called within a specific method?

Tags: c#, logging, aop, postsharp, aspect

I've recently started using PostSharp for one of our project. The aim is to **log method execution time for all the methods being called within a specific method** (representing an specific feature).

What I've done till now is that I've created an aspect (say TimingAspect) and tested it on one method (by writing '[TimingAspect]' above method definition). It's working fine, logging execution time for that method in a separate log file.

As per my knowledge, if I write '[TimingAspect]' on top of a method definition, it only logs for that method and not for other methods being called from this method. Am I right ? So now I'm wondering if there is any way I can **achieve the aim**, i.e. *log method execution time for all the methods being called within a specific method* ?

Comment: @Ronit Singh : Did you find any solution or work around for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your aspect to methods that are called from the target method by implementing [IAspectProvider](http://doc.postsharp.net/iaspectprovider). To find all the called methods you can use [ReflectionSearch](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_reflection_reflectionsearch) class from the PostSharp API.

Below you can find an example of such aspect provider.

```
[PSerializable]
public class TimingAspectProvider : MethodLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        MethodBase targetMethod = (MethodBase) targetElement;

        IAspectRepositoryService aspectRepositoryService = PostSharpEnvironment.CurrentProject.GetService<IAspectRepositoryService>();
        TimingAspect aspect = new TimingAspect();

        MethodUsageCodeReference[] usages = ReflectionSearch.GetDeclarationsUsedByMethod(targetMethod);
        foreach (MethodUsageCodeReference codeReference in usages.Where(u => u.UsedDeclaration.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method))
        {
            if (!aspectRepositoryService.HasAspect(codeReference.UsedDeclaration, typeof(TimingAspect)))
            {
                yield return new AspectInstance(codeReference.UsedDeclaration, aspect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this doesn't cover logging for the methods called from the called methods and so on. My understanding is that you want to log the methods that are called directly from the target method.